# Why Shiny app layout changed when including Rmarkdown files?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, markdown, knitr

I was playing around with a Shiny app that has multiple tabs using `tabsetPanel` and `tabPanel`. Everthing was fine until including a Rmarkdown file into one of the tabs. The whole app was reduced in size after the `.rmd` file was rendered to HTML. Also, the option `number_sections: true` did not do anything. Does anyone know how to work around this? Thanks!

### Video of the issue

[image: Video]

### App.R

```r
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(skimr)
pacman::p_load(markdown)
pacman::p_load(knitr)
pacman::p_load(shiny)

# 1) Define UI for random distribution app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Input: Select the random distribution type ----
      radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",
                   c("Normal" = "norm",
                     "Uniform" = "unif",
                     "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
                     "Exponential" = "exp")),
      
      br(),
      
      # * Input: Slider for the number of observations to generate ----
      sliderInput("n",
                  "Number of observations:",
                  value = 500,
                  min = 1,
                  max = 1000)
      
    ),
    
    # * Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # * Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table, etc. ----
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
                  tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                  tabPanel("RMarkdown", uiOutput('rmd_summary'))
      )
      
    )
  )
)

# 2) Define server logic for random distribution app ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Reactive expression to generate the requested distribution ----
  d <- reactive({
    dist <- switch(input$dist,
                   norm = rnorm,
                   unif = runif,
                   lnorm = rlnorm,
                   exp = rexp,
                   rnorm)
    
    dist(input$n)
  })
  
  # Generate a plot of the data ----
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    dist <- input$dist
    n <- input$n
    
    hist(d(),
         main = paste("r", dist, "(", n, ")", sep = ""),
         col = "#007bc2", border = "white")
  })
  
  # Generate a summary of the data ----
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(d())
  })
  
  # Data Summary ----
  output$rmd_summary <- renderUI({
    HTML(mark_html(knit('data_summary.Rmd', quiet = TRUE)))
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### data_summary.Rmd

````
---
title: "Overview of the Data"
output: 
  html_document:
    number_sections: true
---

<br> 

# Data Statistics

## Skimr

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
skimr::skim(iris)
```
````

## Update

Based on Russ' and Yihui Xie's comments, here is what's needed

```
HTML(mark_html(knit('data_summary.Rmd', quiet = TRUE), 
                   output = NULL, options = list(number_sections = TRUE, toc = TRUE),  
                   template = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly how, but it looks like the `mark_html()` function imports a template by default and that template has CSS files associated with it that overwrite the original shiny CSS. The easiest way to turn that off is to set the template argument to `template=FALSE`.

This means that there is no (or at least minimal) imported CSS for the markdown rendering, so you may have to do some CSS tweaks to the rendered markdown part of the shiny afterwards. I didn't change the markdown file. Here's what the modified UI and server looks like:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(skimr)
pacman::p_load(markdown)
pacman::p_load(knitr)
pacman::p_load(shiny)

# 1) Define UI for random distribution app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
# I added CSS to add cell space the table in the markdown file and add white space at 
# the bottom of the page. More tweaks might be needed. 

  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML("td, th {padding: 10px;} #rmd_summary {margin-bottom: 60px;}"))),
  
# end of UI changes, server changes below
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Input: Select the random distribution type ----
      radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",
                   c("Normal" = "norm",
                     "Uniform" = "unif",
                     "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
                     "Exponential" = "exp")),
      
      br(),
      
      # * Input: Slider for the number of observations to generate ----
      sliderInput("n",
                  "Number of observations:",
                  value = 500,
                  min = 1,
                  max = 1000)
      
    ),
    
    # * Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # * Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table, etc. ----
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
                  tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                  tabPanel("RMarkdown", uiOutput('rmd_summary'))
      )
      
    )
  )
)

# 2) Define server logic for random distribution app ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Reactive expression to generate the requested distribution ----
  d <- reactive({
    dist <- switch(input$dist,
                   norm = rnorm,
                   unif = runif,
                   lnorm = rlnorm,
                   exp = rexp,
                   rnorm)
    
    dist(input$n)
  })
  
  # Generate a plot of the data ----
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    dist <- input$dist
    n <- input$n
    
    hist(d(),
         main = paste("r", dist, "(", n, ")", sep = ""),
         col = "#007bc2", border = "white")
  })
  
  # Generate a summary of the data ----
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(d())
  })
  
# I added the template = FALSE argument

  # Data Summary ----
  output$rmd_summary <- renderUI({
    HTML(mark_html(knit('data_summary.Rmd', quiet = TRUE) , template = FALSE))
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image: unchanged shiny layout]

Comment: Thanks @Russ! Do you know why the `number_sections: true` did not work?

Comment: Not sure, but it wasn't working before the changes I made either. I think it may have to do with using `knit()` instead of `render()`. Will the rmd file change based on input from the shiny? I'm wondering if it might be easiest to render the rmd file first and then include it in the shiny after it's already rendered.

Comment: That's a good workaround. Thanks!

Comment: @Tung I have good and bad news for you. Bad news: since [markdown v1.6](https://github.com/rstudio/markdown/releases/tag/v1.6) (just released to CRAN a few hours ago), `mark_html()` / `mark()` no longer returns text output when the input is a file but generates an output file instead (and returns `NULL`). To return text as before, use `mark_html(..., output = NULL)`. Sorry about that! Good news: since v1.6, sections can be numbered: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/markdown/vignettes/intro.html#number-sections (use `options = list(number_sections = TRUE)`).

Comment: @YihuiXie: Thanks a lot for the headsup! Everything works now